# How to solve this error in my Cucumber Spring Boot Jar: "[...] cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found [...]"?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, cucumber, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In summary, When using "cucumber.api.cli.Main" in my Spring Boot Cucumber jar I get the an error as follows:

> Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found.
> Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.egj.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-springboot-cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>hello-springboot-cucumber</name>
    <description>Sample project to explain how to setup Cucumber in a Spring Boot Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To generate getters, setters, equals, hascode, toString methods -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To convert DTO to Entity and back -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To invoke REST endpoints from Cucumber step definitions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CucumberTest.class, args);
//      io.cucumber.

        final String[] arguments = new String[]{
                "--glue","com.egj.cucumber.hello.bdd.stepdefs",
                "classpath:features"
        };

        cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);
    }

}
```

And this is my directories structure:

[image: Spring Boot & Cucumber App Directory Structure]

Basically, when I run my application from IntelliJ it works fine but when create a jar using

> spring-boot-maven-plugin

and I run the jar using that command:

> java -jar target/hello-springboot-cucumber-1.0.0.jar

I get the error I pointed from the very beginning. Some help would be gladly appreciated.

[image: error when running jar file]

Comment: Did you try with the latest Cucumber version?

Comment: Not yet, I might do @M.P.Korstanje

Comment: A few days went by since I posted the question but I am still going to provide an update.  A few hours after I saw your suggestion I tried resolving the issue by upgrading cucumber but it still did not work. I ended up realizing that only maven-shade-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin allowed me to fix the issue because they allow to build a fat jar and there is no nested jar structure @M.P.Korstanje

Comment: You can write an answer to your own post. It is allowed on SO. And it might help other people.

Comment: Sure, will do ASAP. @M.P.Korstanje